# Modifying an existing MVVM infrastructure by adding View State feature

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, wpf-4.0

I'm going to introduce View State feature in the existing MVVM WPF Application. The objective is to be able to Save and Load (restore) particular state of a control.

The question is more about design and best solution from system flexibility/maintability perspectives.

**Current infrastructure:**

```cs
public abstract class ViewModelBase
{
   protected ViewModelBase(...)
   {
   }
}

// and few more very the same ViewModel classes for different control types
public sealed class GridViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   protected GridViewModel(...) 
      : base(...)
   {
   }
}
```

I'm introduced `IViewState interface` so each specific ViewModel could provide own implementation like `GridViewState class` and going to put it in ViewModel infrastructure in following way: (Idea is to pass type of ViewState as generic parameter)

```cs
public abstract class ViewModelBase<TViewState>
  where TViewState : class, IViewState
{
   protected ViewModelBase(...)
   {
   }

  public TViewState ViewState { ... }
}
```

1. Is it a good idea to attach View State feature to ViewModel?
2. Is it a good solution to introduce tied relation between specific ViewModel typa and ViewState through the generic Type parameter like `class GridViewModel<GridViewState>`?
3. Where and why better to define such methods like `LoadState() / SaveState(),` `IViewState` itself or `ViewModelBase`?
4. Are there another design solutions?

Comment: 1 and 2 looks reasonable
3. LoadState() and SaveState() is nearer to IViewState but for extensibility and maintainability provide a persistence interface to deligate the saving to, this allows implementation of multiple persistence concrete implementation (ex. database, xml, file, ws, ...)

Comment: Regarding Load/Save state I've decoupled it from state itself by creating IViewStateAware<TVviewState> which encapsulate ViewState + both methods

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't persist your domain objects and just rebuild the ViewModels from those when they're loaded? What kind of state would your views hold that your domain classes wouldn't? If it's related to visual elements such as position and location I would push those into a settings class and persist that.

I'm assuming there's some underlying logic and classes which represent your domain, if not then your ViewModels really *are* your domain and your idea is solid.

I'd probably look at something like the [memento](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMemento.aspx) pattern to rehydrate your VMs since they'll likely have a fair few events and other relationships (e.g. property changed events of collection items) which can't be serialized and must be recreated.

There are plenty of persistence patterns out there but judging by your naming and explanation memento looks a good fit.

Comment: ViewModel is complex entity which does not represented by a single domain entity. ViewState should hold UI settings like sorting, columns order, user layout preferrences, etc, this is 10% of data represented by a ViewModel.

Comment: It's common for a VM to represent more than one domain entity but it should still be possible to get back into the current VM state by rehydrating those entities. If there are purely visual elements which you want to persist is there a reason you wouldn't just create a user preferences object and treat it like any other domain entity?

Comment: no, there are an other entities and they are business entities and also there are some customization criterias which are saved into a settings

Comment: I'm a little confused. If you're already saving the view customisations into a settings object then what state are you wanting to save? If it's data that truly doesn't belong in the VM (i.e. you really consider it view state rather than VM state) then I'd probably just save/load it to app.config (or user isolated storage) in the loaded/closed events of the view. If it's fairly complex or you just want to experiment with design patterns then memento seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Currently I'm saving not UI customization settings but user settings like filter values, custom criterias, etc. And this is completely different kind of the settings. And now I'm trying to introduce ViewState, which is aware only on View layout settings like sorting, etc. The problem is some of the ViewState settings will be used by ViewModel, for instance sorting criteria, and some woulld not be used, like columns order, such kind of settings could be handled by View itself.